# SAS : How to overwrite default 97 characters truncation?

Tags: sas

I use `ods tagsets.excelxp`

```
ods tagsets.excelxp
file='C:\xxx\xxx.xls' 
options(autofilter="yes"
            sort="yes"
...
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

Everything is fine except

`WARNING: Data too long for column "Description"; truncated to 97 characters to fit.`

How can I overwrite this, and set a different truncation limit ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that warning applies to the Tagsets but to the Listing destination so turning that off before running the tagset code should help.

Or is it truncating in your excel file?